# Should this retaining wall have drainage

Tags: waterproofing, drainage, landscaping, stone, retaining-wall

Should the wall in the picture below have better drainage (e.g. perforated pipes)? And, if yes, is it possible to add them at this point? The walkway above has the same slate top you see at the very bottom of the picture.

[image]

Comment: I would say there is probably some kind of drainage already there, most likely a foundation drain for the footings on the ground level. If there is not a problem don’t create one.

Comment: That doesn't look like a retaining wall.  Is there soil behind it?

Comment: I'm not sure what's behind it. I guess, dirt. I know that whatever is behind it gets water from the pathway above it.

Answer (score 1):

We try to be helpful on this site and that means that sometimes we post things which are not any direct answer to the question. This posting is one of those times.

You do need to get this fixed:

[image]

This is surely a safety violation in almost any jurisdiction and the extra strain on the wires could result in circuit failure.